# YouTrack Dynamic Channel Online Form

Tags: javascript, workflow, jetbrains-ide, youtrack, online-forms

Is it possible to make dynamic issue form in YouTrack? I mean: if we have here a field "Category" = `Software` then hide "Email address" field.

[image]

In fields edition we've that option but it only works when the issue is submitted.

I've tried to do it with workflow but it doesn't work for me. Even `console.log` to debug wont work and I don't know why :/

Comment: It's not possible to submit a ticket without an email address at all. For other cases of conditional fields, here's the feature request in JetBrains issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JT-74721/Conditional-fields-for-online-form